# On Wpf container tabbing is not loosing focus on button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

A button on wpf container is not loosing focus style while tabbing across the windows.The control does go to the other elements but the button will still have the focus style on it.

Comment: please show your code..

Answer (score 0):

Does the button have IsDefault=True? This will cause the button to always have keyboard focus for the Enter key as long as another control is not capturing the keyboard input.

Comment: Update the question with some XAML so we can get a picture of what is going on